# How to update a value of a variable in Thread class on some condition in the caller

Tags: java, multithreading

Let us say I have two classes, A main class and a Thread class as follows:

```
public class A {
   public static void main(String []args){
         int count = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               count+=10;
               //here on every addition, I want to update the variable countOfAdd of the thread class 

//and when countOfAdd value is in multiples of 5 I want to print a statement
         }
  }

class B extends Thread {
    int countOfAdd;
    @Override
    public void run(){
         //on value received
         count+=1;
    }
}
```

I don't know whether this is possible or not. If it is possible how to do it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about having a setter for `countOfAdd` in your thread ?

Comment: how about creating getters and setters of `countOfAdd` and process conditional update

Comment: @srikanth Why are you using thread here ??

Comment: first describe the whole task, and only then your approach to solve it.

Comment: Have you checked your code in IDE it has compilation error, you can't implements Thread as it is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The normal way to do that is a queue.

Create a [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and make references to it available to both threads.

The main thread should `add()` an element to the queue (e.g. the amount of increment).

The other thread should `poll()` the queue and use this information to update its internal state.

This way none of the intermediate updates are going to be lost between the threads.

#### The quick and dirty way is direct access and locking.

Both of your threads can keep a reference to a common piece of data, and a common lock object (which can just be a `Object commonLock = new Object()`).

Every time *either* thread needs to access the data member, they do it holing a lock, e.g.:

```java
synchronized (commonLock) { commonCount +=1; }  // One thread.
```

```java
synchronized (commonLock) { if (commonCount > 1) {...} }  // Another thread.
```

This is harder to reason about, but can be made serviceable if the number of accesses in each thread is made small, preferably just one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using Thread here but anyway.

**1. Without Thread**

```
public class A {
   public static void main(String []args){
         int count = 0;
         B objectB = new B();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               count+=10;
               //here on every addition, I want to update the variable countOfAdd 
//of the thread class and when countOfAdd value is in multiples of 5 
//I want to print a statement
              objectB.setCount(YourInput);// set your value
              if(objectB.getValue()%5==0){
                //do your task
              }

         }
  }

class B {
    int countOfAdd;
    public int getCount(){return countOfAdd;}

    public void setCount(int ){this.countOfAdd =countOfAdd;}
}
```

**2. With Thread**
Use Pub-sub pattern 
[Implementation of pub sub pattern in Java](https://medium.com/@sapanparikh18/implementation-of-simple-pub-sub-in-java-27a8d31bac31)